# Adding new rows of data between existing rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames and I would like to connect them together in such a way that after ordering the data in descending order, the data frame `df2` goes between the rows of the `df` table. I would also like to add dates to the newly added rows so that each date follows the existing days of the dates.

**My data:**

```
df
  Product       Date Value
1       A 2017-07-10    80
2       A 2017-07-01   150
3       B 2017-08-10    40
> df2
  Product  Month Value
1       A   July    90
2       A   July    50
3       B August    30

> result
  Product       Date Value
1       A 2017-07-01   150
2       A 2017-07-02    90
3       A 2017-07-10    80
4       A 2017-07-11    50
5       B 2017-08-10    40
6       B 2017-08-11    30


df <- data.frame(Product = c("A","A","B"),
                 Date = c("2017-07-10","2017-07-01","2017-08-10"),
                 Value =c(80,150,40))

df2 <- data.frame(Product = c("A","A","B"),
                 Month = c("July","July","August"),
                 Value =c(90,50,30))
```

Incorrect solution for:

```
df$Value[1] <- 500 ; df$Value[2] <- 50; df$Value[3] <- 400

Product       Date Value
1       A 2017-07-01    50
2       A 2017-07-02    90
3       A 2017-07-10   500
4       A 2017-07-11    50
5       B 2017-08-10   400
6       B 2017-08-11    30

Should be:

Product       Date Value
1       A 2017-07-01    50
2       A 2017-07-02    50
3       A 2017-07-10   500
4       A 2017-07-11    90
5       B 2017-08-10   400
6       B 2017-08-11    30
```

Comment: Number of rows in `df` and `df2` would always be the same?

Comment: Merging these data frames is tricky because you have conflicting columns. Your desired outcome shows a column "Date" but there is no way to get from "July" in df2 to `2017-07-02` in result. If it weren't for that, I would simply combine them with cbind and sort them afterwards.

Comment: If `df2$Month[1]` is `August`, what is the expected date?

Comment: @Darren Tsai I expected the next day occurring after the date of df

Comment: @Ronak Shah Yes, number of rows in df and df2 always be the same.

Comment: If `df$Value[1]` is `50` and `df2$Value[2]` is `80`, what is the expected output? In this situation you will get 2 successive `July`, right? The current two answers cannot deal with it.

Comment: For the values `df$Value[1] <- 50 and df2$Value[2] <- 80` code works ok, but I found values for which code works incorrectly. I added them in the comments below.

Comment: Your description is not clear, could you rephrase it? Right now, we are looking at input and output and trying to guess what you want to do. If it is difficult to explain you might want to include 2-3 examples and show output for them so that it is clear what you are aiming to do.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to increment the dates in `df` by 1 day, replace `Value` from `df2` in `df` and bind to original dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)  

df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = Date + 1) %>%
  arrange(Product, Date) %>%
  mutate(Value = df2 %>% arrange(Product) %>%  pull(Value)) %>%
  bind_rows(df) %>%
  arrange(Product, Date)

#  Product       Date Value
#1       A 2017-07-01   150
#2       A 2017-07-02    90
#3       A 2017-07-10    80
#4       A 2017-07-11    50
#5       B 2017-08-10    40
#6       B 2017-08-11    30
```

Comment: The code is not working properly, e.g. try `df$Value[1] <- 500 ; df$Value[2] <- 50; df$Value[3] <- 400`

Comment: What would be your expected output for this case? Maybe I have misunderstood your question because in my answer nothing changes based on change in `Value` column.

Comment: I add incorrect solution after your code in my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
df$Date = as.Date(df$Date)
df = df[order(df$Value, decreasing=T), ]

nr = nrow(df) * 2
result = data.frame(Product = rep('', nr), Date = rep(NA, nr), Value = rep(NA, nr))

idx = c(1:nr)
result[which(idx %% 2 == 1), ] = df

df2 = data.frame(Product = df2$Product, Date = as.Date(df$Date, '%Y-%m-%d') + 1, Value = df2$Value)
result[which(idx %% 2 == 0), ] = df2

result$Date = as.Date(result$Date, origin = "1970-01-01")

> result
  Product       Date Value
1       A 2017-07-10   500
2       A 2017-07-11    90
3       B 2017-08-10   400
4       A 2017-08-11    50
5       A 2017-07-01    50
6       B 2017-07-02    30
```

Comment: The code is not working properly, e.g. try `df$Value[1] <- 500 ; df$Value[2] <- 50; df$Value[3] <- 400`

Comment: Unfortunately not. Check my answer for those values in the question.

Comment: You could be more specific. You said in "descending" order. In line 2, I order the df in on 'value' in descending order. If you want to order it on 'Date', you can use this: df = df[order(df$Date, decreasing=T), ]. If you want to order it on 'Date', but not in descending order, then you can use this: df = df[order(df$Date), ]